# resolveComponentFactory overriding css

Tags: angular

In my `Component A`, I have created another component using `resolveComponentFactory` and `createComponent()` and I wanted to use the css `styleUrls` of my `Component A` to change some parts of component created. There are any way to do this?

I tried to use `!important` and had no effects/changes on in `<ng-template></ng-template>`, which contains the html of component created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-deep` for example:

```
::ng-deep .myCustomCss {
    background: red;
}
```

See: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Please note that it does say `deprecated` however there was a github post by an angular team member saying that this is the way to go until a long term solution is found.